# Display progress of long running operation on Welcome page

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to check for updates of my app during the installation, while showing the process on a form of Inno Setup.

So basically this:

```pascal
WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := 'Checking for update ...';
DownloadFile(VersionURL, LatestVersion)
WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := 'New version available.';
```

Below is a working code, except, when `CurPageChanged` is called, the form is not yet ready. It's not shown properly until the checking of new version is done. See the screenshot. It's working fine while stepping through the code with debugger.

What am I missing? Any workaround?
Main goal is to avoid waiting for the version checking process without any feedback, because it feels like irresponsibility.

Two pictures.

- What I get:

  [image]
- What was desired

  [image]

```pascal
#if defined UNICODE
  ; signed 64bit integer, but using only positive numbers, 0 .. 9223372036854775807
  ; examples of version string:
  ; 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..127
  ; 0..65535 . 0..65535 . 0..65535 . 0..32767
  #define Int64_OR_LongWord "Int64"
#else
  ; LongWord, 0 .. 4294967295
  ; 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..255 . 0..255
  ; 0..65535 . 0..65535
  #define Int64_OR_LongWord "LongWord"
#endif

[Setup]
AppName=Check Version
AppVersion=1.2.3
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  SetupURL = 'http://hu.hu/huhu.exe';
  VersionURL = 'http://hu.hu/version.txt';
  sizeNumOfSubsets=4;
  sizeSubset=256;

function VerStrToNum(const strVersion: String): {#Int64_OR_LongWord};
var strVersionRemaining: String;
    tmpIntSubset: Integer;
    i: Byte;
begin
  // add period at the end, so that any valid number should end with a period
  // empty strVersionRemaining means all numbers are read and the rest are zeroes
  // v1.2.3 = v1.2.3.0.0
  strVersionRemaining := AddPeriod(strVersion);
  for i := 1 to sizeNumOfSubsets do begin
    if strVersionRemaining <> '' then begin
      tmpIntSubset := StrToIntDef(Copy(strVersionRemaining,1, Pos('.',strVersionRemaining)-1), -1);
      strVersionRemaining := Copy(strVersionRemaining,Pos('.',strVersionRemaining)+1,Length(strVersionRemaining));
    end
    else tmpIntSubset := 0;   
    if tmpIntSubset <> -1 then begin
      Result := Result * sizeSubset + tmpIntSubset;
    end                                                
    else begin
      // if version string format invalid, just return 0,
      // error would just confuse user. RaiseException('Invalid format of version string');
      Result := 0;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function DownloadFile(const URL: string; var Response: string): Boolean;
var
  WinHttpRequest: Variant;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    WinHttpRequest := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    WinHttpRequest.Open('GET', URL, False);
    WinHttpRequest.Send;
    Response := WinHttpRequest.ResponseText;
  except
    Result := False;
    Response := GetExceptionMessage;
  end;
end;


// --- to show correct text when comming back to Welcome Page by pressing PREV button
var oldWelcomeCaption: String;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then begin
    WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := oldWelcomeCaption;
  end;
  Result := true
end;

var PanelDownloadButton: TPanel;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var LatestVersion: string;
begin
  case CurPageID of
    wpWelcome: begin
      // the Welcome Page was still hidden at this point
      WizardForm.Visible := True;
      // THIS IS WHAT I WAS MISSING:
      WizardForm.Repaint;
      oldWelcomeCaption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption;
      WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := oldWelcomeCaption + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + 'Checking for update ...';
      if DownloadFile(VersionURL, LatestVersion) then begin
        if VerStrToNum(LatestVersion) > VerStrToNum('{#SetupSetting('AppVersion')}') then begin
          WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := oldWelcomeCaption + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + 'New version available.';
          // PanelDownloadButton.Visible := True;
          // xxx Run downloaded setup, exit this one
        end
        else WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := oldWelcomeCaption + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + #13 + #10 + 'No new versions.';
      end
      else WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption + #13 + #10 + Copy(LatestVersion,Pos(':',LatestVersion)+2,Length(LatestVersion));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**edit:** The Code above is fixed now, in case anybody wants to use the version checking.
I will add a link to final code with button and download functionality later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `WizardForm.Repaint` to force the form to draw fully:

```pascal
WizardForm.Visible := True;
WizardForm.Repaint;
```

---

See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Repaint

> Forces the control to repaint its image on the screen.
>
> Call `Repaint` to force the control to repaint its image immediately.

Comment: Great, that was it. I will modify code in the original question to include it, in case someone would want to use it. Dikec.